# Transform flat array

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

im stuck with my XSLT script. This is my input:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<root>
    <ID>12345563</ID>
    <ID>12345564</ID>
</root>
```

what i tryed was this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
      <batchParts>
          <xsl:for-each select="root">
              <Test><xsl:value-of select="." /></Test>
          </xsl:for-each>
      </batchParts>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thats my current ouput:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><batchParts><Test>
    12345563
    12345564
</Test></batchParts>
```

what i want to accomplish is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><batchParts><Test>
    <Test>12345563</Test>
    <Test>12345564</Test>
</batchParts>
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSLT stylesheet that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its conformance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, or 4.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want this instead :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
      <batchParts>
          <xsl:for-each select="root/ID">
              <Test><xsl:value-of select="." /></Test>
          </xsl:for-each>
      </batchParts>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```